# How do you find the minimum value of a 2d list and remove it

Tags: python

I have a 2d list with all of the lists having the same format and I want to arrange it so it is going up in numerical order.
Here is the list:

```
list = [["a", -50], ["b", 23], ["c", 5], ["d", 44], ["e", 23]]
```

How do i end up with something which prints

```
data_list = [["a", -50], ["c", 5], ["b", 23], ["e", 23], ["d", 44]]
```

I'm avoiding using `.sort()` or any other built in functions as I want to keep the strings with the appropriate number

Comment: `sorted([["a", -50], ["b", 23], ["c", 5], ["d", 44], ["e", 23]],key = lambda x:x[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use builtins and still keep the association. E.g.:

```
data_list = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
```